# Unity3d Destroy any objects that exist before instantiating

Tags: c#, instantiation, destroy

This may seem infantile, but I'm just not getting it.
This program has different buttons that show or hide a canvas with the relevant information, in this case, an Oil Change.

When the button is pressed, it opens the oil change canvas, gets the information from the database and displays that information from an instantiated prefab. That works fine. The problem comes when you click the same button or another button and come back to the same canvas. The information is double or triple or quadruple, you get the idea. It multiplies every time you go back to it.

Obviously, the game objects must be destroyed before instantiation, but:

1. I'm not sure what to check for; is it the temp variable used for instantiation or the prefab? I've tried defining it at the top of the script, any other time, I get an error of unassigned use.
2. I'm not sure the best time to call the function. I'm guessing once you hit the button.

   ```
   public void ShowAllOilChanges()
   {
       for(int i = 0; i< OilChangeList.Count; i++)
           {
               ocObj = Instantiate(OilChangePrefab);
               OilChange tmpOilChange = OilChangeList[i];
               ocObj.GetComponent<OilChangeScript>().DisplayOilChanges("Date of Service: " +tmpOilChange.ServiceDate, "Place of Service: " +tmpOilChange.Location, "Mileage: " +tmpOilChange.Mileage, "Labor: " +tmpOilChange.Labor, "Oil Brand: " +tmpOilChange.OilBrand, "Oil Price: " +tmpOilChange.OilPrice, "Filter Brand: " +tmpOilChange.FilterBrand, "Filter Price: " +tmpOilChange.FilterPrice, "Purchase Place: " +tmpOilChange.OilFilterPurchaseLocation);
               ocObj.transform.SetParent(OilDisplayparent); 

           }
   }

   public void DestroyOilChange()
   {
       Debug.Log("Before" +ocObj);

       Destroy(ocObj);
       Debug.Log("After" +ocObj);
   }

   public void OpenOilWindow()
   {

           if(windowOpen==false)
           {
               windowOpen=true;
               OilCanvas.enabled=true;
               BatteryCanvas.enabled=false;
               BrakeCanvas.enabled=false;
               TireCanvas.enabled=false;
               PlugCanvas.enabled=false;
               MufflerCanvas.enabled=false;
               CustomCanvas.enabled=false;
               DestroyOilChange();

           }
           else if(windowOpen==true)
           {
               windowOpen=false;
               OilCanvas.enabled=false;

           }
   }
   ```

If someone could walk me through, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There's too much missing info to assist. I cant even tell what file(s) these methods are in and who calls them. Would have to show more of the complete flow (IMO) for anyone to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this backwards. First thing I did was to create tags for the various types of objects that needed to be deleted. Then I added them to their respective prefabs. This function is called when you open a canvas(window) and when you close one.

```
public void DestroyObjects(string tag)
{
    GameObject[] Obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(tag);
    if(Obj==null)
        return;
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(Obj.Length);
        for(int i=0; i< Obj.Length; i++)
        {
            Destroy(Obj[i]);
        }
        Debug.Log(tag + "Objects Destroyed!");
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone like me.